# A sum related to the first moment of quadratic $L$-functions at $s=1$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series

Let $(\frac{m}{n})$ be the Jacobi quadratic symbol defined for positive squarefree odd integers $n,m$. Does the following sum go to infinity?
$$
\sum_{1\leq n \leq (\log x)^{100} } \mu^2(2n) \sum_{(\log x )^{100} < m \leq x} \left(\frac{m}{n}\right) \frac{\mu^2(2  m )}{m},
$$ where $\mu$ is the M"obius function. The sum over $m$ looks as the tail of $L(1,(\frac{\cdot}{n}))$ where $L$ is the Dirichlet $L$-function associated to the quadratic character modulo $n$.

Answer (score 1):

If in doubt use the square-root cancellation heuristic.
You can think of this sum as
$$
\sum_{n < (\log x)^{100}} \varepsilon_n X_n
$$
where $\varepsilon_n$ is a random sign and $X_n$ is another random variable usually of size
$$
\sqrt{\text{Var}(X_n)} := \sqrt{\sum_{m > (\log x)^{100}} \frac{1}{m^2}} \asymp (\log x)^{-100/2}.
$$
Then you expect that the optimal bound for the entire sum to be
$$
\sqrt{\sum_{n < (\log x)^{100}} \text{Var}(X_n)} \asymp 1
$$
However based on probabilistic heuristics (e.g law of iterated logarithm) you'd expect there to be some additional fluctuations of the order of $\sqrt{\log\log\log x}$ so I'd guess that this sum can go to infinity on a subsequence.

Comment: what is $\epsilon_n$ here? I guess $X_n$ models the sum over $m$ but I don't see what $\epsilon_n$ models.

Comment: $\epsilon_n$ models the sign of the sum over $m$